# Function in excel to search an array of strings for two different sub strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am having trouble at the moment finding a function to search through an array of cells in excel in order to count the amount of times a cell contains two words.

e.g. The functions I have tried so far:

```
    =COUNTIF([array],AND("text1","text2"))
```

and

```
    =COUNT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text1",[array])*SEARCH("text2",[array])),1,0))
```

or

```
    =SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text1", [array])*SEARCH("text2",[array])),1,0))
```

So I was hoping for feedback if there is a different/easier way to do this or if there are errors in constructing my excel functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `COUNTIFS` with wildcards, I.e

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*text1*",A:A,"*text2*")`

Comment: It didn't work out, returned 0 when I tried it on a random array set

Comment: Did you insert the  * wildcards? I couldn't make them display above? What are the text values?

Comment: Actually yeah that did it with the wild cards huge help thanks!

Comment: @cars10 - thanks for the edit - I can normally make that work but I was on my ipad and I couldn't get the right symbol!

Comment: Well, yes, could not quite figure it out, with your almost 30k credits you can hardly be a newbie! ;-) - and thanks for the `SUMPRODUCT()` ...

Answer (score 0):

*As a side note:*

For those of us who still hang around with ancient Excel versions: the following will work even with Excel 2003:

```
=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("text2";A1:A200));1;0));IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("text1";A1:A200));1;0))
```

You have to confirm the formula input with `<cntrl><shift><return>` for it to become a **matrix formula**, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: You can do that a little more simply with SUMPRODUCT - then it also doesn't require array entry, i.e.`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND("text1";A1:A200))*ISNUMBER(FIND("text2";A1:A200)))`